# Rendering a extended datatable on selection change of another extended datatable

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Q1 :I'm trying to render a rich:extendedDataTable(say Table-B) on 'selectionchange' event of another rich:extendedDatatable(say Table-A). The rendering part is fine. But the style class 'rf-edt-r-sel'(which is used to highlight a selected row) is not removed from the original row in Table-A (where the ajax request was triggered ),even after selecting a different row in Table-A.

Also, This problem is not reproduced when the list associated for Table-B is null in the Managed bean. What should be done to solve this issue?

Q2: When Table-B is rendered with a not-null list, I perform a row selection on Table-B which triggers an Ajax call to the Managed Bean. But after the completion of the ajax request,I'm not able to trigger ajax calls from Table-A on its row selection. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the rich faces jar. I was earlier using rich faces 4.0 jars. I replaced all rich faces jars with rich faces 4.3.4 jars. The tables work fine now.